# Variable not parsed JSON

Tags: php, json, disqus

I am trying to parse JSON values from Disqus to PHP variables and I was able to do 90%, but for some reason one specific variable won't work.

Both $comment->message and $comment->thread have values in the JSON below.

JSON: https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?api_key=0B7l7oEVh6xH6EN5BEcEDg4R7tq4RiEmhuLyjnavaUKyOLx23bo099ltdnH9f2p6&forum=greetingtheworld&limit=4

```
<?php

$endpoint = 'https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?api_key=0B7l7oEVh6xH6EN5BEcEDg4R7tq4RiEmhuLyjnavaUKyOLx23bo099ltdnH9f2p6&forum=greetingtheworld&limit=4';

$j=0;
$cursor=0;

// Standard CURL
$session = curl_init($endpoint.$cursor);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // instead of just returning true on success, return the result on success
$data = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// Decode JSON data
$results = json_decode($data);
if ($results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');

// Comment response
$comments = $results->response;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $name = $comment->author->name; <-- THIS WORKS
    $comment = $comment->message; <-- THIS WORKS
    $thread = $comment->thread; <-- THIS DOESNT WORK
    // Get more data...
    echo '<li class="recentcomments">
        <span class="comment-author-link">';
    echo $name;
    echo '</span> on <a href="2013/10/take-a-deep-breath-and-just-be/index.html#comment-116">';
    echo $comment . $thread;
    echo "</a></li>";
}

?>
```

When doing the above, the below works fine and returns the correct value:

```
$comment = $comment->message;
```

However, the below returns an error:

```
$thread = $comment->thread;
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/... on line 27

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: We can't see the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code you stored `$comment->message` to `$comment`.So `$comment->thread` dont work because you have changed the value of `$comment` in before statement.
**So you must store `$comment->message` to any other variable like `$message`.**

Comment: That is so obvious!

Thanks a lot, mate. Sometimes we just need different eyes to look at our codes.

Nearly embarrassing!

Much appreciated!